# Windows compile instructions for mod_go.so

Tags: go

Is it possible to compile [mod_go.c](https://github.com/idaunis/mod_go/blob/master/mod_go.c) successfully and produce the Apache module (mod_go.so) for [GOLANG](https://golang.org/) in Windows environment?

Unfortunately i can not find any detailed instructions such as type of C++ compiler, apache version etc as well as what steps i have to follow?

Regards

Comment: Perhaps not. It could be related to Go plugins, which work only on Linux

Comment: BTW did you consider the other way round: use Apache on Linux (as most people do), so switch your web server to Linux?

Comment: If i had used Apache Linux, definitely i would not have placed this question here and discuss it. The real challenge is to find the other way around, how to do it in Windows and why not in MacOS. Besides golang is a multi-platform environment as far as i know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably **that is not possible**, but I leave you to check.

[Go plugins](https://golang.org/pkg/plugin/) are only supported on Linux. So if you absolutely need to code Apache modules in Go  (which requires [dynamic loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) of shared object produced by the Go compiler, that is a [*plugin*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)) coded in Go), you'll better switch to Linux. BTW the linker model of Windows is very different from Linux, so it won't change easily and I won't be surprised that Go won't have plugin on Windows for a few years.

Linux [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) (actually a POSIX [feature](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/dlopen.html)) and its shared libraries ([ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) shared objects, containing [position-independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) code) are very different from Windows `LoadLibrary` and [DLL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library)s.

Read Levine's [*Linkers and Loaders*](http://iecc.com/linkers/) book and (for Linux) Drepper's paper [*How To Write Shared Libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf)

So if you badly need to write this year (e.g. before the end of 2018) a plugin in Go to be used by Apache, I strongly recommend switching your Apache server machine to Linux.

BTW, it looks like your [`mod_go`](https://github.com/idaunis/mod_go/blob/master/mod_go.c)  don't use Go plugins (but communicate with some external process, I leave you to study its source code, I only glanced into it) Perhaps using [FastCGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI) could be simpler, since [Go has FastCGI](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/fcgi/) support. Probably Windows' Apache could be configured to talk to some FastCGI application (notice that FastCGI is *not* [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface)).

<sup>(I don't know Windows, never used it, but read a few things about its weird -and IMHO inferior to Unix- linking model)</sup>